# How to convert a string to an array according to a specific separator?

Tags: php, html, explode, implode

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "it, is, a, test";
```

Now, I want this: *(separator is `,`)*

```
<small>
 <a href='#'>it</a>
 <a href='#'>is</a>
 <a href='#'>a</a>
 <a href='#'>test</a>
</small>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) ..

```
$str = "it, is, a, test";

$res = explode( ', ', $str );

echo "<small>";
foreach($res as $result){
    echo "<a href='#'>" . $result . "</a>";

    }
echo "</small>";
```

https://ideone.com/XvIF67

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "<small><br/>";
$str = "it, is, a, test";
$arr = explode(', ',$str);
foreach ($arr as $data)
    echo "<a href='#'>" . $data . "</a><br/>";
echo "</small>";
```

Comment: Thanks. Among these answers, if you mark one as accepted, the user will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**explode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like

```
echo "<small>";
$wordArray = explode(', ',$str);
foreach($wordArray as $word) {
    echo "<a href='#'>".$word."</a>";
}
echo "</small>";
```

Comment: Thanks, +1, worked correctly. just why `explode()` ? when should I use `implode()`?

Comment: @stack please use this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/051e29/implode-and-explode-function-in-php/

Comment: This approach has a small **problem**: In the behind of all word *(except first one)* is a space, How can I remove it? In other word, how can I use `trim()` in your solution?

Comment: Well, No need to `trim()` in here, just add a space after `,`.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<pre><br/>";
$str = "it, is, a, test";
$arr = explode(', ',$str);
echo "<small>";
foreach($arr as $item){
echo <a href='#'>$item</a>
}
echo "</small>";
```

Comment: Where are `<small>` and `<a>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$str = "it, is, a, test";
$arr = explode(', ', $str);
echo "<small>\n";
foreach ($arr as $word) {
    echo "  <a href='#'>$word</a>\n";
}
echo "</small>\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, +1, worked correctly. just why `explode()` ? when should I use `implode()`?

Comment: @stack `implode` joins .. `explode` separates! :}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<small><a href='#'>".implode("</a><a href='#'>", explode(', ',$str))."</a></small>";
```

As you see, in first `explode()` function separates the string and creates a array of keywords, Then `impode()` function combines them and creates exactly what you need.

**Output:**

```
<small>
 <a href='#'>it</a>
 <a href='#'>is</a>
 <a href='#'>a</a>
 <a href='#'>test</a>
</small>
```

Here is a [demo](https://3v4l.org/ZbkT4).